# I got this error when I run discord.js bot

Tags: rest, discord.js

When I run discord bot with discord.js

```
[my\path\discord.js\bot]
> node bot.js
C:\Users\username\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\APIRequest.js:33
    agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RESTManager.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)

[my\path\discord.js\bot]

>
```

I think it's rest client syntax error
How can I fix it?

Comment: umm bro, are you using discord.js v13?

Comment: send your code...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Discord.js v13, you need to be using Node 16.6.0+ as stated in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome). The error you're receiving is most likely due to your Node version being below that since `??=` should work if you're using the right version of node.

[Logical nullish assigment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) (`??=`) is relatively new to Node (15.14.0 according to [node.green](https://node.green)), you need to update it to at least 16.6.0 for Discord.js v13 to fully function.